# The meaning of object A movable relative to object B

Tags: patent-infringement

I am reading one patent. One claim contains the statement: object A movable relative to object B. My understanding is that object A can be movable, B is fixed and the motion is relative to object B. Can I  fix object A and move object B? Does my proposal infringe the claim?

Answer (score 1):

Someone would need to know much more about the patent and your planned work-around to provide a very useful answer. I can say that if that is the actual claim wording it is un-artful. The reason claim language uses relative motion between two objects is to avoid this loophole. Relative motion should be used in the sentence so it covers any way that the described motion can be done regardless of which stays still, if anything. For example, a claim on microwave ovens with motorized lazy susans should say the microwave radiation source and the object being cooked move relative to each other.

Comment: Thanks, George. I am reading the patent US7068825B2. http://www.google.com/patents/US7068825. About claim 64, it is a device claim. I use almost the same device, but totally different method. Currently I don't have one workaround. In the claim the word movable is used. In your reply, you use "move relative to each other" to describe the relative motion, but in the claim the author uses "moveable relative to said scanner". English is not my native language, so I don't know the exact difference between the two description. Can I avoid the infringement by fixing the surface.

Comment: I don't. Think so. If you are referring to "a Z calibration surface receiving said projected pattern moveable relative to said scanner between at least two Z distances separated by a known amount . . .", it is written in a general way. The pattern could be moved up and down, or the scanner could be moved up and down, or both could be moved. Also, you need to avoid each and every claim and this patent has way more than the average patent.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question. Claim 64 is a device claim. I use almost the same device and the method of using the device for calibration is totally different. How do you usually to handle the situation?